# xslt + javascript -> a full functional small scale web site?

Tags: xslt

is it possible to build a full functional, small scaled website, without java or python or perl or php? and with xml files as simple data storage?  therefore, i can move my website any where I want.....

any experiences like this to share?

thanks.

Comment: Possible? Yes, yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the site is going to be read-only, then yes, it is possible (just several static pages with javascript for dynamic effects). If the functionality of the site implies sharing changes made by users, you will need to involve server side programming anyway.